# Function eats my space characters

Tags: function, vim, escaping, statusline

I wrote a function

```
function! BrickWrap(data, icon_align, icon_left, icon_right)
    if empty(a:data)
        return ''
    endif

    let l:brick = (a:icon_align ==# 'left') ? a:icon_left . a:data :
                \ (a:icon_align ==# 'right') ? a:data . a:icon_right :
                \ (a:icon_align ==# 'surround') ? a:icon_left . a:data . a:icon_right :
                \ (a:icon_align ==# 'none') ? a:data :
                \ ''

    if empty(l:brick)
        echom 'BrickWrap(): Argument "icon_align" must be "left", "right", "surround" or "none".'
        return ''
    endif

    return l:brick
endfunction
```

in order to format some data which gets displayed inside my statusline, e.g.:

```
set statusline+=%#User2#%{BrickWrap('some_data','surround','\ ','\ ')}
```

The example above should wrap the data with a space character on each side. But what happens actually is that it only appends a space character to the right but not to the left. In order get a space character displayed to the left I have to pass two escaped space characters (`'\ \ '`). I have to mention that it only happens in the statusline. If I'd `:call` the function it works as expected.
Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use backslashes and whitespace with `:set`, you need additional escaping, see `:help option-backslash`. So, your backslash in front of the space is already taken by the `:set` command. (You can check this via `:set stl?`)

If coming up with the correct escaping is too hard, an alternative is to use the `:let` command instead:

```
:let &statusline = '...'
```

However, then you must only use double quotes in your statusline value, or deal with the quote-within-quote escaping then.

Comment: No it's not really too hard. That's just a fact one has to know to avoid "unexpected" surprises :) Good hint to use `let` instead though!